# Glitches in FFT Spectrum

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fft, naudio

My FFT works in a way. I tested it with some frequency sweeps, I can clearly see the peaks but I get some weird glitches and strong noise all over the spectrum. The signal jumps up and down and some bars just disappear sometimes. I tried to read the values and get NaN sometimes. What am I doing wrong here?

```
    void FFTLive()
{
    int sampleCount = 8192;

    NAudio.Dsp.Complex[] complex = new NAudio.Dsp.Complex[sampleCount];

    float[] dat = new float[sampleCount];
    source.clip.GetData(dat, source.timeSamples);
    for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
    {
        complex[i].X = dat[i];
        complex[i].Y = 0;
    }

    NAudio.Dsp.FastFourierTransform.FFT(false, (int)Mathf.Log(sampleCount, 2), complex);

    for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
    {
        float value = 10 * Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Log10((complex[i].X * complex[i].X + complex[i].Y * complex[i].Y)));
        Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(-10 + (float)(i / 20), -16 + value, 40), new Vector3(-9 + (float)(i / 20), -16 + value, 40), Color.green, 0.002f);

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**
I added the window and check for 0 but it still has a huge amount of noise as it seems.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount; i++)
    {
        complex[i].X = dat[i]*(float)NAudio.Dsp.FastFourierTransform.BlackmannHarrisWindow(i,sampleCount);
        complex[i].Y = 0;
    }
    


    NAudio.Dsp.FastFourierTransform.FFT(false, (int)Mathf.Log(sampleCount, 2), complex);


    for (int i = 0; i < sampleCount / 4; i++)
    {
        float value = 0;
        if (complex[i].X + complex[i].Y != 0)
            value = 10 * Mathf.Abs(Mathf.Log10(100 * (complex[i].X * complex[i].X + complex[i].Y * complex[i].Y)));
        Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(-10 + (float)(i / 20), -16, 40), new Vector3(-9 + (float)(i / 20), -16 + value, 40), Color.green, 0.0002f);

    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Solved it. I forgot that the sampled data is 2 channels so I mixed those two up which caused all the glitches. So I divided the data array in half, only taking every second entry which should be from just one channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least two problems.

You don't check that the magnitude input to the last Log10() isn't zero.  That will cause NaNs.

You aren't using a non-rectangular window function before the FFT to remove windowing artifacts (from non-integer-periodic waveforms that are discontinuous between the end and beginning of the FFT aperture).  Try using a Von Hann or Hamming window.

Comment: So I added the window like in Update #1

and a check for when the value becomes 0 but it still doesn't work.
It seems there's a huge amount of noise but I take the data directly from an audio file.
I draw the waveform with the same data and it turns out fine.